# What are the NIST/FBI requirements for Fingerprint readers, and Iris scans?

Tags: authentication, biometrics, fingerprint, nist

**Background**

I'm trying to locate the US government standard for fingerprint readers and mobile devices.

I heard in passing that the iOS fingerprint reader only scans 9 points, where the FBI requirement is 30 points.

The iris scan is reportedly arriving in some Android phones in the future.

**Question**

- What are the technical requirements of biometric scanners for NIST and the FBI?
- What consumer devices (if any) meet those standards?

Answer (score 2):

The DHS released [HSPD-12](https://www.dhs.gov/homeland-security-presidential-directive-12) in 2004, which called for a mandatory standard for federal employee identification and verification. NIST responded six months later with [FIPS 201](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_201), the minimum requirements to meet the objectives of HSPD-12.

FIPS 201 refers to Special Publication 800-76 ([SP 800-76](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-76-2.pdf)) for "the requirements for collection and formatting of
biometric information". SP 800-76 goes on to reference the ANSI/NIST Fingerprint Standard [AN2011](http://biometrics.nist.gov/cs_links/standard/AN_ANSI_1-2011_standard.pdf) for the preparation of biometric data suitable for FBI background checks, as well as the FBI's Electronic Biometric Transmission Specification [EBTS (download)](https://www.fbibiospecs.cjis.gov/Document/Get?fileName=Master_EBTS_v10_-_FINAL_20130702_new_figures.pdf).

Other referenced Special Publications from FIPS 201 are:

- [SP 800-73](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-73-4.pdf) Interfaces and card architecture for storing and
  retrieving identity credentials from a smart card
- [SP 800-78](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-78-4.pdf)  Requirements for cryptographic algorithms
- [SP 800-79](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-79-2.pdf) Requirements for the accreditation of PIV Card issuers
- [SP 800-87](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-87r1.pdf) Unique organizational codes for Federal agencies
- [SP 800-96](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-96.pdf) Requirements for the PIV Card reader
- [SP 800-156](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-156.pdf) Format for encoding the chain-of-trust for import and export
- [SP 900-157](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-157.pdf) Requirements for issuing derived PIV credentials

While I don't know of any smartphones that are FIPS 201 compliant, there are many compliant peripherals that can be used with iOS and Android devices.

A searchable list of FIPS 201 compliant devices can be found at https://www.idmanagement.gov/IDM/IDMFicamProductSearchPage